# "Be nice" is not working. It's just a fact

Tags: discussion, be-nice-policy

I used this website a long time ago but got turned off by how rude people were. So I stopped using it.

I asked a question today in a field I'm not familiar with and instead of answers got snark.

The question was also downvoted, so now I'm probably not going to get an answer.

In other words, the site is useless. It's supposed to be a place to get answers, but if you ask in one of the technical forums, odds are you won't get an answer if your question is simple or low-level.

"Be nice" isn't working, and the reason is that there's no punishment when people are rude.

So, I'll go find the answer somewhere else, and hope that you people at some point finally figure out how to make this site actually welcoming to non-experts and beginners.

Comment: I guess you mean this question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/540293/how-can-a-dc-power-source-cause-a-crystal-to-oscillate I don't see any snark, just comments on your question, no one was rude to you.

Comment: @MarkKirby you could argue the new year wishes are noise, chit chat. That is not where comments are for. I wouldn't call that rude but maybe different views exist on that.

Comment: @rene Sure, great point, I hate chit chat on my posts when I am waiting for an answer, I can totally see how someone could think it was rude, especially on SE.

Comment: One interpretation is that they asked rhetorical  questions because they thought it was a homework question.

Comment: At face value, it is a very simple physics question that could be answered by reading the [corresponding Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectricity). If that is not case (the title *hints* at it), then you should make it more clear what the real question is.

Comment: Try to put yourself in the shoes of someone trying to answer. Could you answer the question given the provided information?

Comment: I *think* your ***real question*** was why (some) [piezoelectric buzzers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/540293/how-can-a-dc-power-source-cause-a-crystal-to-oscillate#comment1400691_540293) only require a DC voltage (some [operate with a DC voltage](https://www.americanpiezo.com/standard-products/buzzers.html) - without an external electronic (AC) oscillator). But that is a lot of guesswork - you need to provide such details. We are ***not*** psychics or mind readers (even though some of us pretend to be).

Comment: [The question spelled out](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/540293/how-can-a-dc-power-source-cause-a-crystal-to-oscillate#comment1400699_540293).

Comment: Am I right or not about my guesswork?

Answer (score 15):

Thanks for your kind words.

It is unfortunate that you didn't provide details about what you posted and what kind of feedback you got you feel was not helpful to improve your post.

While you venture elsewhere we'll try to figure out on our own what went wrong and improve on our guidance for both posters and curators.

Just for the record: "be nice" was replaced with a complete ["code of conduct"](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: I'm not here to snitch, but I can if you want. Would it be helpful to provide details?

Comment: @AlGorithm: It is materially impossible for anyone to help you unless you tell us what the problem is in the first place.

Comment: @AlGorithm technically that would invalidate my answer and tbh your question (and comment on your question) didn't read as an well meant invitation for a discussion. If that  has changed now then feel free to see if you can add factual stuff and what you hoped would have gone different. That is something we can work with. I'll see after your update if my answer can be reworded or is better deleted. One advice: Don't come here angry or for venting. That frustration is not something we want to deal with. Keep it about the post.

Comment: @Kevin it's crystal clear what the problem is: downvotes. People take it as personal offense of the worst kind, always did, and always will. No policy or code of conduct will ever solve this basic human behavior.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/540293/how-can-a-dc-power-source-cause-a-crystal-to-oscillate

Comment: Can you tell me a legitimate reason for the downvotes?

Comment: @AlGorithm update your question but the reason for downvotes is something that can only be answered by the folks on the meta of Electronics.se. You should have an option on your EE.SE question to ask a Meta question about it there, despite you not having 5 rep. If you're interested in my guess: you didn't show what you do understand about a crystal and how you are planning to apply a DC voltage to it. Remember you are talking to engineers not to philosophers. Questions asked out of curiousity do well on forums, not so on SE Q/A sites.